# Crear tabla en PostgresSQL con nombre de la fecha actual

Tags: python, postgresql

Mi idea es crear una tabla en postgreSQL que varíe su nombre en función del día que sea, o de la fecha.

La idea de código para crear sería el siguiente código, pero obviamente no funciona y no estoy seguro que sea posible lo que quiero.

```
from tkinter.constants import *
from datetime import datetime
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect(database="ControlAcceso", user="postgres", password="Color1984")

print("Database opened successfully")

name_tabla = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
print(name_tabla)

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE registro
  (DNI          INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
  Nombre        TEXT                NOT NULL,
  Profesor_ID   INT                 NOT NULL,
  CodigoLlave   CHAR(50)''')

print("Table created successfully");
print(name_tabla);

con.commit()
con.close()
```

¿Alguna idea de como poder realizarlo?

Comment: Puedes usar [alter table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-alter.html#id-1.5.4.8.12)

Comment: Si, pero me sigo encontrando con el mismo problema, cuando pongo el comando 

    ALTER TABLE nombre_tabla rename to date

me lo cambia a 'date' no a, por ejemplo, 30/05/2022

Comment: Estuve viendo un poco en internet y me temo que tendrás que crear una función de postgresql que haga eso por ti (no se del todo como crear esas funciones) o un código de Python.

Answer (score 0):

Le he estado dando vueltas a tu última constestación y he encontrado que lo mejor sería definiendo una variable

```
name_tabla = 'reg_'+(datetime.today().strftime('%Y'))+(datetime.today().strftime('%m'))+(datetime.today().strftime('%d'))
```

y luego cambiar el nombre de la tabla mediante

```
cur.execute('ALTER TABLE registro rename to'+' '+ name_tabla)
```

Comment: Ya veo! Recomendación: esto: `datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')` hace lo mismo que `(datetime.today().strftime('%Y'))+(datetime.today().strftime('%m'))+(datetime.today().strftime('%d'))`. Hasta diría que es más optimizado.